# Why I got so many connection events on Node's HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, websocket, socket.io

I have a web application using socket.io. It runs on localhost:8000 on my local machine. In order to find an annoying resource leak in my application, I tried to log out the connection events on my HTTP server:

```
server.on('connection', function(conn) {
    //log out connection details
});
```

When I open the page inside my browser after the page loads, I can see multiple connection events in the log - something like these:

```
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54148
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54149
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54146
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54152
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54144
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54155
```

The strange thing is that I don't create a WebSocket connection after page load - only if the user clicks on a button. But I haven't clicked on any button and I still see these strange connections.

If I click on my button to connect with socket.io to my server, the log shows a new connection:

```
connection established: 127.0.0.1:54155
```

Fortunately every connections which I saw in the log were closed after some time - so I guess it couldn't be the reason of my resource leak.

But I'm still curious: what causes these connection events? And why is the port number so strange (not 8000 on which my server listens)?

**Edit:**

My server config is not a special one. In `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var configSettings = require('./configSettings');

var socketIOServer = require('./server/socketServer')(io); // config socketServer
require('./server/static.js')(app, express); // static middleware
require('./server/routes.js')(app, configSettings); // routes

exports = module.exports = server;

exports.use = function() {
     app.use.apply(app, arguments);
};

exports.configSettings = configSettings;
```

In `start.js`:

```
var server = require('./server');

var port = server.configSettings.serverPort;
var serverIpAddress = server.configSettings.serverIpAddress;
server.listen(port, serverIpAddress);
```

Comment: The port numbers are those of the _client_, not the server. Can you see your browser making those connections (in the dev tools window)?

Comment: This could explain the strange port numbers then. Is it possible that every single HTTP request causes a connection event? (i.e. requesting a favicon, a CSS file, etc.)

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, yes. But there should be a reason for the browser to think that it can find resources on your socket.io server; perhaps you can add some more context to your question (about your server setup, if you're also running the HTTP server from the same port, etc).

Comment: I use socket.io with express and both listen on the same port (8000). It's also strange that every request from the browser have different ports...

Comment: It's common that source ports are different for each request. Can you show your server setup?

Comment: I edited my post, so you can check my server setup however I think my code is just the typical Express/Socket.io configuration without any specialities.
Most probably my question is answered - a connection event should be fired for every established TCP stream and for every HTTP request there should be a TCP connection in the transport layer. Just the ports were so strange, that's why I thought it's an error.

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that the log messages were coming from socket.io, but they are coming from the HTTP server. In which case they _are_ being generated for every request to the server, inclusing JS/CSS/favicon). In other words, that's normal behaviour :-)

Comment: Yes, it's coming from the HTTP server :) In the opening post I included the code with which I log the messages.
(Unfortunately I cannot check your comment as an answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connections you're logging from the HTTP server are to be expected and are related to the resources that are being used on your HTML pages (JS, CSS, images, favicon, etc).

The port numbers you're logging are the client side port numbers. While not random, they will change for every new connection that's being set up to your server. After the resource has been delivered to the client (and depending on keep alive, some extra time), the connection will be closed.

In general, Node can handle thousands of concurrent connections.

This obviously doesn't solve your resource leak, but it explains the connection events you're seeing.